# Powerbuilder Create File

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm trying to check if a File Exists (INI) 
If not.. it should create the File with the proper strings.

How do I that?

I tried..

> s_text = "[DATABASE]"   + "~r~n" + &
>
> ```
>           "Server="   + "~r~n" + &
>
>           "UserId="   + "~r~n" + &
>
>           "Password=" + "~r~n" + &
>
>           "DB="   + "~r~n"
> ```
>
> FileWrite(config.ini", s_text)

but it says invalid argument to file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing if the file exist, there is the `FileExists( filename )` that returns a boolean. That function only needs a file name to perform the check.

On the opposite, `FileWrite()` needs to work on an **opened file**. It is given a "file number" that is generated by a call to `FileOpen()` (and that file number should also be given to `FileClose()` at the end of the process).

Why not looking at the PowerBuilder documentation? There is a sample for that : from the PB IDE, press <kbd>F1</kbd>, look at the `FileWrite PowerScript function` section, then press the <kbd>Example</kbd> button. (Surprisingly, the example does not mention `FileClose()` but you DO need to call it ;o)

Don't forget to check for invalid file numbers (for example if the file name does not exist, or if the file is already in use).

**EDIT:** as the OP clarified in the comments that he would like to be able to call `SetProfileString()` on a non-existing ini file (that cannot create a new ini file), here is an example of new ini file creation :

```
int li_file
string ls_ini = "config.ini"
li_file = fileopen(ls_ini, LineMode!, write!)
FileClose(li_file)

SetProfileString(ls_ini, "Database", "Server", "host") 
SetProfileString(ls_ini, "Database", "UserId", "foo") 
SetProfileString(ls_ini, "Database", "Password", "bar") 
SetProfileString(ls_ini, "Database", "DB", "baz")
```

Comment: I did call and tried those Functions. my question was how to create that file, could I open a non existent file using FileOpen() so i could filewrite them? I am doing a Filewrite because the file doesnt exist yet, if it does i would use setprofilestring instead because im opening an INI.

Comment: @Sid: Concerning the file creation, the help seems clear : given the _fileaccess_ you give to `FileOpen()`, it can open an existing file to read, or create a new file (or rewrite an existing one) to write into.  Now, concerning the `SetProfileString()` on a non existing file, I have tested that it cannot create a new file. But it can fill an empty one. I have edited my answer to provide an example.

Comment: sorry sir, but my question was not using those functions but how could I create the file if its not existant. but thanks, i got some work around and finally did it. Thanks again

Comment: @Sid: did you tried the snippet I have posted? **The lines 3 and 4 are actually addressing your problem of creating a file that does not exist.** After that you can use `ProfileString` and `SetProfileString` at your will (and it avoid the need of a datastore to fill a text file - that I feel it is a weird and complex mean for that task)...

Comment: thanks sir, just got it. did not know that FileOpen can be used even if the file doesnt exists. it worked

Answer (score 0):

This was my approach.

if the INI file was not existant.

> datastore ds_1
>
> ds_1 = CREATE datastore
>
> // d_dummy is a Tabular DW with 1 column serves as string, char(100)
>
> ds_1.dataobject = 'd_dummy'
>
> l_row = ds_1.InsertRow(0)
>
> ds_1.SetItem(l_row, 'dummy', '[DATABASE]')
>
> l_row = ds_1.InsertRow(0)
>
> ds_1.SetItem(l_row, 'dummy', 'Server=')
>
> l_row = ds_1.InsertRow(0)
>
> ds_1.SetItem(l_row, 'dummy', 'UserId=')
>
> l_row = ds_1.InsertRow(0)
>
> ds_1.SetItem(l_row, 'dummy', 'Password=')
>
> l_row = ds_1.InsertRow(0)
>
> ds_1.SetItem(l_row, 'dummy', 'DB=')
>
> ds_1.SaveAs("INIFILE.ini", Text!, FALSE)

then i used the ProfileString() and SetProfileString()